# Google Chrome keeps opening this new tab - virus?

Tags: google-chrome, virus

Recently (starting about 2 weeks ago), when I click on something (usually a link) in Chrome (on Windows 7), there is probably a 1-5% chance (a couple of times per day) Chrome will open this page on a new tab:

[Phone Emails](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?ref=vu&id=com.andropk.myphoneemails&nu=1)

I didn't install any new extension, I doubt it is caused by extensions.

Another weird behaviour (that may or may not be related):
Starting about a month ago, is when I click a link with target=_blank, it is **sometimes** opening it in the same tab.

I'm not the only one seeing [Phone Emails](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?ref=vu&id=com.andropk.myphoneemails&nu=1): See this [similar thread](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20141107201647AA33GjP)

Anyone has any idea what this could be?

**EDIT:**
After a full week of enabling/disabling extensions, I finally found that it was caused by an extension called Video Grabber (not in Chrome Web Store anymore) that I might have installed years ago.

Comment: Delete your chrome profile see if that helps

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. How do you do that? (and how to back it up if it's not obvious)

Comment: The location of the user profile for chrome is well documented as for backing it up just copy the folder before you delete ot

Comment: It might also help to see if `chrome://policy` has something interesting to show

Answer (score 2):

Wow that's a very unlikely that something legitimate is auto opening that site ,

It probably is because you clicked something ..
Try this, I found it useful to me.

1. Check your extensions. Make sure there is nothing weird on there.
2. Reinstall Chrome
3. Check installed software in your PC. Make sure no software was installed without your permission. If there is some, remove it.

If these steps don't resolve your problem, try switching browsers.

Oh you're using phone right, so if I've faced this problem , 
Below suggestions might help

1.Check is there any apk(application either from playstore or others) were installed. Identify what application and then google it if other user might face the same problem.
2.Recheck your chrome settings. Make sure nothing weird on there

Otherwise, this is my opinion. Sometimes I have installed certain games and application from 3rd party and then after installing and use it for few times. Sometimes, either once a day or more chrome automatically open up and went to certain sites in playstore. Its nothing to do with virus bzoc that is another way of promoting certain application to people. 100 % not virus I think bcoz it linked up with playstore. If link to another website then it may be.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hadi! No weird extensions, I'm disabling all extensions now, let's see what happens. Sorry I forgot to mention I'm on Windows 7 on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I found that extension MAPSCOUT was added to Chrome and it was popping up new TABs as a "service" for me  Dec, 2018